# What is "to hire the locale"? I thought "to hire" was only used with people

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am listening to a conversation between a woman and a manager of party hire company. They are talking about food, music band, car parking etc.
I have to answer the question "How much will it cost to hire the locale?"

Could you explain what "to hire the locale" is, please?

I saw the usage of the verb "to hire" in regard to people. As for me, it is strange to see this verb with an inanimate resource.

Google does not show examples of the usage of this phrase.
It is an IELTS listening training.

Comment: To hire the locale = to hire (rent) this particular plot of area, or this particular flat or this particular house (for an event, since it's a party hire company). "Сколько будет снять это помещение\это место?"

Comment: A synonymous phrase in AmE would be **to rent the venue**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In that conversation I also heard the word "venue". Thank you for a good remark.

Comment: Thank you for adding more detail about why a dictionary didn't help you - I went ahead and reopened your question. It helps us write better answers if we understand the source of confusion.

Comment: @ColleenV My the very first reaction on "on hold" was like https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Table-Flip-Guy.jpg

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov Putting a question on hold usually means that we think it needs to be clarified before people try to answer it. This helps you get better answers and keeps the folks answering it from possibly wasting their time telling you something that you already know. It also helps people with the same question find your question. Maybe someone is trying to figure out a different sentence where "to hire" is used with an inanimate object, but it doesn't have "locale" in it. The [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) thread has more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Locale* just means "place," so in reference to party planning it'd be the place where the party is happening.

So "to hire the locale" would mean to pay to rent out the space where you're having the party.

Note that in American English you tend to only *hire* people, not places. You'd more likely *book* a locale, or *rent* it. As an American English speaker, I find the phrasing "hire the locale" very strange. As @eques points out, though, British English speakers would be fine with the phrasing.

Depending on additional context, hiring the locale may also refer to hiring the people who work at the party location – caterers, security, other event staff.

Comment: It's probably a matter of regional variation. In the UK, you "hire" a tuxedo ("rent" in the US) or you "hire" a cab ("call" or "take" in the US), so similarly, "hiring" a locale/venue may not be odd in a culture which "hires" clothes and cars

Comment: @eques Very interesting, I did not know that. Are you a British English speaker? If so, would you think there is any ambiguity with "hire the locale" in terms of whether it's referencing the space or the people who work there, or would you automatically just assume it's a reference to the space?

Comment: I'm not a British English speaker; I'm just familiar with many of the differences (more common ones anyways) between that and American English. "hire the locale" like "rent the venue" probably refers to the space, but often renting a space could include the staff (based on context); I don't really see "hire" implying the people being included anymore than "rent" would.

Comment: Well thanks for the note. I've edited the answer. Hopefully that clarifies a bit.

Comment: I'm a British English speaker. To me "hire the locale" isn't something I would say (nor have I ever heard it specifically) but it makes sense to me. "Hire" is used to mean the temporary possession of things (eg cars) usually for a fee. It is not used for long-term use of land, where verbs like "rent" would be used (eg for a home). However "hire" does seem to be used for the short-term use of physical space. In contracts I draft in the entertainment etc industry one often sees "dry hire" (ie. hiring a space without any facilities like catering).